# Scan Postgres composite type

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a composite type defined for use in a table:

```
CREATE TYPE duration AS (
    hours NUMERIC,
    minutes NUMERIC
);

CREATE TABLE foo (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    my_duration duration
);

INSERT INTO foo (id, my_duration) VALUES
(1, ROW(1, 30));
```

How can I scan this with `database/sql`? When I implement the scanner interface with

```
func (d *Duration) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    log.Println(value)
    if value == nil {
        *d = Duration{
            Hours:   -1,
            Minutes: -1,
        }
        return nil
    }
    if duration, ok := value.(Duration); ok {
        *d = Duration(duration)
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Failed to scan duration")
}
```

The type of the interface comes out as `[]uint8`, and the value itself is an encoded array, something like `[40 50 44 51 51 41]`. How can I parse the composite type properly?

edit: I have a `Duration` struct defined as

```
type Duration struct {
    Hours   int
    Minutes int
}
```

Comment: Non-standard types require you to do the conversion from the bytes ([]uint8) to your Duration struct. It's possible, but I'd suggest a simpler approach; to store the duration as a single integer number of minutes. Also, consider using Go's [time.Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)

Comment: Why do you invent your own data type? To store a duration, a column of type [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) would be a better choice. Or use a single integer column as Mark suggested. Both solutions will give you much less problems in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte slice `[40 50 44 51 51 41]`, when converted to a string and printed to stdout looks like this `(2,33)`, [see link](https://play.golang.org/p/tjOopJ3vglt).

So you can see that what you're getting back from the db is a tuple with two integers separated by a comma. With that knowledge you can implement the Scanner interface that parses the custom data type values.

```
func (d *Duration) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if b, ok := value.([]byte); ok {
        ss := strings.Split(strings.Trim(string(b), "()"), ",")
        if len(ss) != 2 {
            return errors.New("unknown Duration format: " + string(b))
        }

        h, err := strconv.Atoi(ss[0])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        m, err := strconv.Atoi(ss[1])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        d.Hours, d.Minutes = h, m
    } else {
        d.Hours, d.Minutes = -1, -1
    }
    return nil
}
```